# How to pass JSON String as Request Parameter to other service

Tags: java, spring-boot, jakarta-ee

I have two services running. One service will generate a JSON response. Below is the generated Json response.

```
{ "appliedCostMatrix": { "regionCostMatrix": "","costAreaCode": "",    "costBoundaryId": 0,    "isActive": "Y",    "costRegionCode": "",    "regionTypeCode": 3,    "regionTypeDescription": "California",    "solveTypeDescription": "Coaxial"  },  "networkSolveRegion": "CALIFORNIA"}
```

Now To save the response i have to call other service and have to pass this Json as string.

```
http://localhost:8080/putSolvedRoutes?responseJson=(Above Mentioned JSON string)
```

Can any one tell me the best way to achieve this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Use POST method with body contains json instead of GET

Comment: Or URLEncode your JSON. It is a bad way of course but... JSON is just a format of String... Proper way use POST and JSON string in the body.

Comment: Thanks Nick Ryan. Your answer helped me!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What have you tried? Your tags imply this is a Spring question so within the context of Spring boot, set up your controller (that receives the second request you send with the json data) as follows:

```
@RestController
public class YourRestController {
    @RequestMapping(value="/your/endpoint", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<String> someMethod(@RequestBody YourDTO data) {
        // business logic here
    }
}
```

and send the request with whatever client you are using, in post.

If the client is also Spring, have a look at the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-resttemplate.html) for one possible way to solve the problem. A brief example:

```
@Service
public class YourService {
    private final RestTemplate rt;
    public YourService(RestTemplateBuilder rtb) {
        this.rt = rtb.build();
    }
    public YourDTO someRestCall(String param) {
        return this.rt.postForObject("/your/endpoint", YourDTO.class, param);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks William, Your answer helped me!!